# How to use Regex to 'capitalize and replace' in Visual Studio Code's snippets?

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I want to create a snippet on Visual Studio Code .

I tried to manually join the Regex but it never worked like my expect:

input:
`idss-static-frame.spec`

expected result:
`IdssStaticFrame`

my Regex:
`${TM_FILENAME_BASE/((\\w+(?=\\-))*(\\w+(?=\\.))*)((\\-)*)/${1:/capitalize}/g}`

actual result:
`IdssStaticFrame.spec`

I couldn't remove `.spec` string

Comment: `(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)` replace with `$1$2$3` ?

Comment: My colleague gave me an answer。`${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(?:\\.spec$)|(?:^|-|\\.)(.)/${1:/capitalize}/g}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of filenames, you may use

```
"${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(\\w+)(?:-|\\.\\w+$)/${1:/capitalize}/g}",
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AN9ezJ/1)

**Details**

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `(?:-|\.\w+$)` - `-` or `.` + 1 or more word chars at the end of string.

You may use

```
"${TM_FILENAME_BASE/([^-]+)(?:-|\\.\\w+$)/${1:/capitalize}/g}",
```

To match file names that contain chars other than just word chars as `[^-]+` matches 1 or more chars other than `-`.

Answer (score 0):

```
"${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(\\w+)[-\\.]|.+/${1:/capitalize}/g}",
```

see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LzZiUH/1).